# How to relate existing user in web service/API end with social(google, facebook etc) login from mobile when they login second time onwards

Tags: php, android, ios, facebook-login, google-signin

I am designing an API for a mobile app(android+ios). The mobile app will have social login, facebook and google login actually. The oauth login procedure will be done by mobile app developers. I am not concerned about this part. But I need to create a new user when one user first sign in using google/facebook. Obviously, in case of social login there will be no password saved/created, only email, name etc will be created in database. I want to know how I will recognize those users who are log in using social apps? I cannot rely on email address provided by the mobile apps and generate token for that user associated with the email. In that case, anyone can get the token by providing only email.